# Simple optimization in cvxopt CVXOPT glpk MILP. No optimization

Tags: python, linear-programming, convex-optimization

I'm using CVXOPT to solve this simple optimization problem:

```
maximize X1 + X2 
s.t:
 X2 + X6      = 2
 X1 + X2 + X5 = 2
 X1 + X4      = 2
 X1           >=0
 X2           >=0
```

Obviously this has a really simple solution

```
 X1 = 1 
 X2 = 1
```

(all the rest are 0)

However, cvxopt get it completely wrong. 
this is what I do:

```
>>> print A
  [ 0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.00e+00]
  [ 1.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00]
  [ 1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00]

>>> print b
[ 2.00e+00]
[ 2.00e+00]
[ 2.00e+00]

>>> print G
[-1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00 -1.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00]

>>> print h
 [ 0.00e+00]
 [ 0.00e+00]

>>> print c
[-1.00e+00]
[-1.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
```

(all of the above are "matrix" type of cvxopt)

> > > print glpk.ilp(c,G,h,A,b,I=set([0,1,2,3,4,5]))[1]

```
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.43
5 rows, 6 columns, 9 non-zeros
6 integer variables, none of which are binary

Preprocessing...
3 rows, 5 columns, 7 non-zeros
5 integer variables, none of which are binary
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| =  1.000e+00  max|aij| =  1.000e+00  ratio =  1.000e+00
Problem data seem to be well scaled
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part = 3
Solving LP relaxation...

GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.43

3 rows, 5 columns, 7 non-zeros
*     0: obj =   0.000000000e+00  infeas =  0.000e+00 (0)
PROBLEM HAS UNBOUNDED SOLUTION
None
```

Comment: Unless you are omitting something in your problem formulation above, there is not one but infinitely many solutions to the problem if you are assuming _X1_ and _X2_ real, and three solutions when you require integer values: (2,0), (1,1) and (0,2).

Comment: Yes, that is true. I just fixed this moments a go. Thanks

Comment: @Zahy Would you mind posting the code that fixed your problem?

Comment: I do not have access to it anymore. But CVXOPT was right, I was wrong! there is an unbounded solution (the array inputs were wrong)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code implementing the above:

```
import cvxopt.glpk
import cvxopt
c=cvxopt.matrix([1,1,0,0,0,0])
G=cvxopt.matrix([[1.0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0]])
h=cvxopt.matrix([0.0,0.0])
A=cvxopt.matrix([[0.0,1,0,0,0,6], [1,1,0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1,0,0]])
b=cvxopt.matrix([2.0, 2, 2])
(status, c)=cvxopt.glpk.ilp(-c,-(G.T),-h,A.T,b,I=set([0,1,2,3,4,5]))
print(status, c)
```

And the result is:

```
optimal [ 0.00e+00]
[ 2.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
[ 2.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00]
```

I'm not sure how to get all the solutions ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the LP you have supplied, GLPK is right.

(0.5,0.5,1.5,1,1.5) is feasible

and an extreme ray is (1,1,-1,-2,-1).